# Is any tool for taking MySQL Dump Automatically with a particular time?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, tools

I am using VS2010 and MySQL for my project. My client wantw to take mysqldump every day like a daily backup. I want to give my client a tool for taking mysqldumps on a particular time schedule.

Do you know any tool that can fulfill my requirement?

Comment: Several, but it depends on MySQL edition, Engine used, OS+filesystem, 3rd party plugins or extensions (eg XtraDB). So, can you add more detail please to help us to help you...

Comment: Your question is too broad - and a "shopping list". Google "windows mysql automatic backup" or similar - then come back to us with particular questions. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Windows (because of you mention VS2010).

Simply create a "scheduled job" either through the Windows UI (e.g. `start control schedtasks`) or the `at` command. This taks should run [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) at the desired time.

Here are some links that explain how to create a scheduled task in Windows:

- [Task Scheduler: Management Services | Microsoft Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758861%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [List, add, edit, delete Windows Scheduled Tasks from the command-line | Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/51524/list-add-edit-delete-windows-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line)
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Comment: I assumed a remote MySQL instance, not local. Especially when it goes live.

Comment: @gbn: you can schedule jobs on a remote system as well.

Comment: If the remote server is Solaris using ZFS with Community edition, you'd need to use a ZFS snapshot with MySQL stopped via crontab or such...

Comment: @gbn: you could still schedule a `mysqldump` using cron.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you deploy an existing maintenance script which takes care not only of taking the dump (trivial), but also of deleting the old backup files, naming them accordingly, handling various possible failures etc etc. Eg. I use [backup-manager](http://www.backup-manager.org/) and I'm quite pleased with it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 1.5-year-old post ([mysqldump with automatically generated export name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60964/mysqldump-with-automatically-generated-export-name/60968#60968)) on how to create mysqldump backups in a Windows environment using DOS Batch Programming.

You can create a Task Scheduler job that launches the batch file on some timeframe.

## EPILOGUE

Looking for 3rd tools is not worth time, effort, or the money if it can be scripted.